# Get git commit generation number

Tags: git, version

I'm normally use `git describe` to generate version and build numbers for my builds. In trying to improve the method to handle cases where no tags exists I ran into "[Git Commit Generation Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702821/git-commit-generation-numbers)" which could be a useful number.

Is the generation number stored and if so is there an easy way to retrieve the number?

I know there's at least one alternative approach in using `git rev-list --count HEAD`. While I use the hash in the build number as well it's not really adequate as it loses all sense of order.